# TYPO3 - 404 page instead of exception

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm running `TYPO3 6.2`

I got some errors in my log because robots/spiders tried to access bad URLs on my website ; When I test the URLs I get a TYPO3 Exception page with a lot of details about the related extension :

[image]

In such case, I'd like to display the 404 page.
Below my parameters :

```
[FE][pageNotFound_handling] = /404/
[FE][pageNotFound_handling_statheader]
[FE][pageUnavailable_handling] = /404/
```

Same issue when I test http://www.mycompany.com/xxxxx_anything_xxxx/, i get a 400 Bad request page and not my 404 page.

http://www.mycompany.com/404/ works great by the way, but the 404 page do not display. What am i missing ?

Comment: Is it an extension you developped yourself?

Comment: @StatiX Yes, and the exception is displayed when bad controller/view values are tested in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is passing the wrong value to the entity, within the request.

This is your speaking URL:  `http://www.mycompany.com/xxxxx_anything_xxxx/`
And your URL is generated so: `index.php?tx_yourext_plugin[entity]=xxxxx_anything_xxxx`

You have also an action in your controller which looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\Entity $entity
 */
public function actionNameAction(\Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\Entity $entity) 
{
   ...
}
```

> This is wrong because you send a string, and the identifiers are uids,
>   and must be an existing UID.

**RealURL fix**

```
[
        'GETvar' => 'tx_yourext_plugin[entity]',
        'lookUpTable' => [
            'table' => 'tx_yourext_domain_model_entity',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'IF(path_segment!="",path_segment,title)',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
            'expireDays' => 180,
            'enable404forInvalidAlias' => true
        ]
    ]
```

**Or removing your Dependency Injection from your action and it will be like this:**

```
/**
 * @param string $entity
 */
public function actionNameAction($entity){...}
```

Another way to fix this is by using TypeConverters. https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_property_1_1_type_converter_1_1_object_converter.html

**UPDATE**

Another Hint is to use `config.contentObjectExeceptionHandler = 1` in typoscript. But firstly i would try to resolve the problem with that link, because you pass there different data types. Using realURL you have a little control of what kind of data should be passes in a dynamic url.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I am going to try it today. What about the mysite.com/blablablablablabla error, why doesn't it redirected on the 404 page ?